# God won't start Resque workers: rake aborted! non-absolute home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, resque, god

I'm getting the following error in log/resque-0.log:

```
rake aborted!
non-absolute home
/srv/myapp/current/Rakefile:4
```

If I start a worker manually using the same command God uses, it starts up just fine:

```
QUEUE=* RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/rake -f /srv/myapp/current/Rakefile environment resque:work
```

I've tried running that command under the 'rails' user and the 'root' user (which God runs under). Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the problem may be in your Rakefile, please post your Rakefile and god script.

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra environment in yours between "Rakefile" and "resque"

My god scripts usually look like this:

```
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development"
rails_root = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || "/path/to/app"


God.watch do |w|
    w.name = "resque-task"
    w.group = 'resque'
    w.interval = 30.seconds
    w.start = "/path/to/rake -f #{rails_root}/Rakefile resque:work QUEUE=* RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"

    w.uid = 'gazler'
    w.gid = 'gazler'
```

Comment: Didn't seem to fix the problem. It runs great when I start it on the server via SSH, but it's failing when god tries to run it (same error).

Answer (score 1):

So part of the problem is shadow_puppet trying to resolve your path, but if you're actually trying to use shadow_puppet or something else that tries to expand path on ~ (like Capistrano for example) make sure to include:

```
w.env = {"HOME" => "/users/home/dir"}
```

That fixed this problem for my situation (driving cap from a god-monitored resque worker).

Answer (score 0):

Ok turns out I just had to remove shadow_puppet from my Gemfile. Not sure why I had it in there in the first place, maybe it was a holdover from an old version of Moonshine.